# Getting the correct day between a string containing the week

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I've got this string '5/25/15-5/29/15', and a page that loads a table with monday-friday. I would ideally like to put each day in the table.

For example:

```
Monday - Tuesday - Wednesday - Thursday - Friday
 5/25  -  5/26   -   5/27    -   5/28   -  5/29
```

How can I accomplish this in php/html? Or javascript etc.

update:
I need this to be universal to any date string that I give it, each date will be the same format. But it has to work for the string '6/29/15-7/3/15' as well.

edit:
Also, not sure why I got downvotes on this. Maybe the answer is more clear than I can see. Sorry about that.

Comment: This is not difficult to do. Have you tried anything?

Comment: have a look at basics as http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: @Epodax I would have no issues getting the string itself, if days didn't sometimes start over. For instance, the week 6/20/15-7/3/15. I could easily just explode the string to pull out the number, but that wouldn't work with this example I've just given.

Comment: @Answers_Seeker He only has a range of two dates so your comment is invalid.

Comment: @keikoku92 I need to actually pull the dates from the string, I know how to use tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comment you say you need to pull the dates from the string, using the `DateTime` class and some of its methods will help you do that (In `$string` you can put any range.)

```
<?php
$string = '5/25/15-5/29/15';
$datesExpl = explode('-', $string);

$date1 = new DateTime($datesExpl[0]);
$date2 = new DateTime($datesExpl[1]);
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);

echo $date1->format('d-m-Y')."\n"; 
for($i = 1; $i <= $interval->days; $i++){
    $nDate = $date1->modify('+1 day');
    echo $nDate->format('d-m-Y')."\n";
}

/* 
RETURNS:
25-05-2015
26-05-2015
27-05-2015
28-05-2015
29-05-2015 
*/
```

Comment: how can I use this to output each day seperately? For example, I tried $nDate[0] to get the first date, but was not successful.